# How study the neighborhood of a point?

Tags: matlab

Good Afternoon,

How can I study the neighborhood of a point P(x,y) of a matrix? for example in the configuration 8 connexe my point P(x,y) has 8 neighbor and I want to extract the one which have  the minimal value and obtain its coordinates

for example :
    `r=rand(5)` and I want to study the neigborhood of `r(2,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, all you need is to do

```
sub=P(x-1:x+1,y-1:y+1)
[v i]=min(sub(:))
```

Then `v` is the minimum value and `i` is its index in the vectorized  submatrix. Finding the index in the original one based on the values of `x` and `y` is then trivial (just keep in mind that matlab is column-major).

Comment: But, how if I want to know neigborhood of r(1,1). MATLAB gives me notification that array must be positive integer or logical. How?

Comment: @YohanesSetiawan  Since MATLAB indexation starts at `1`, when you use `P(x-1:x+1, y-1:y+1)` you end up looking outside of the matrix. A trivial solution is just to do this: `P(max(1,x-1):min(image_height,x+1)  ,  max(1,y-1):min(image_width,y+1)`. Another solution is to pad your image (add zeros to the borders).

Comment: Alright. How about if I want to have s neighbors? Is there any way to make it general (automatic) in any input of neighbors (as I mentioned "s neighbors")?

Comment: @YohanesSetiawan Depends on what you mean by automatic? Do you mean vectorized? If speed is not an issue then what would be wrong with just a for loop? Also, is this in some way related to you question about the circular neighbourhood?

Comment: I mean, if in this case is only 8 neighbors, how to code with n neighbors? This is related with my question since 8 neighbors means 3x3 local window (neighborhood) with the pixel x as the center.

Comment: @YohanesSetiawan If that's a 2D image then you can't have more than 8 neighbours. If you mean a mask, then just adjust the indexes `i,j` in  `P(i,j)`.

Comment: @YohanesSetiawan Also, I don't want to be rude, but you need to change the way you interact on this site if you want to get useful answers. Currently you questions follow this pattern: you start with a very vague and poor quality question (e.g. undefined notations, incomplete problem, wrong use of terms), then try to add the information that already should have been in the question through hastily written comments that add to the confusion. On top of that, your questions have a "give me the code" vibe to them (even the one you posted on the matlab forums). Show what you have tried, be precise.

Answer (score 1):

You know that neighbors in this case will lie on [x,y] + [-1,-1], [-1, 0] ... [1, 1]. For the moment simply ignore 2 things - that these points might fall outside of matrix, and that center is included in them. When you do ignore these 2, you end up with

```
neighbors = r(x-1:x+1, y-1:y+1); % 3x3 matrix.
```

Which is trivial to find a minimum of, and its position.

Now, re-considering those 2 omissions: 
First you should pad the matrix by nan to take care of `index out of range` problem (or simply don't look at edge points, you usually end up with more troubles from them than their worth anyway). 
Then, to exclude center you should make a mask:

```
mask = [true, true, true; true, false, true; true, true, true];
```

Finally, finding minimum neighbor could be as simple as:

```
[minValue] = min(neighbors(mask));
```

This is indeed great for finding min value, but almost useless to find min position. Well, here it is simple, 5th point misses because of this mask, in general mask might be of some larger circular shape (if you consider not just direct neighbors but say all points with distance < 3), and it becomes a pain to map this linear index back to the original points.

A simple workaround would be

```
neighbors(~mask) = nan; % set values you don't want to nan.
[minValue, minPosLinear] = min(neighbors(:))
```

At this point, simply reshape minPosLinear to coordinate and add coordinate of the center.

This procedure is easily extended to searching for any other shape of points - simply make a large enough padding (or exclude large enough bands of points on the edge), make large enough initial rectangular window, plus suitable mask.

Comment: But, how if I want to know neigborhood of r(1,1). MATLAB gives me notification that array must be positive integer or logical. How?

Comment: @YohanesSetiawan Yeah, this is the "don't look at edge points" mentioned in answer. If you want to include these edge points, the simplest is to pad matrix with nan: `extR=nan(size(r)+2); extR(2:end-1,2:end-1)=r;` and then look at `extR(2,2)` instead of `r(1,1)`.